# Comparing Data on Two Separate Tabs to Find Key Differences to Summarize on a Third Tab (Key Identifier is a User ID)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

**We start with two 3-column lists across 2 tabs (July & August)**

[image]

**In addition to the July & August tab, we have a Highlights tab which will highlight 4 key changes across the two lists**

[image]

**ON HOLD**

- User ID on the August list whose Live Date < Todays Date (which is manually entered on the Highlights Tab Cell C2)

***What I Have Tried***

- Entered in Cell N6 of the Highlights Tab
- =IFERROR(IF($C$2>August!C2,August!A2," "),)***

***Result:***

[image]

***Desired Result:***

[image]

***Problem: How do I get the formula to not leave blank rows or 0 values once it has no more criteria to check?***

Comment: Hi - Yes, I keep getting a notification to add more detail. The only solution provided was that "This seems like a good use of a Power Query" with no additional details. I have provided a more detailed explanation and a solution to 1-2.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback - this is not "Give me the formula" question. I have provided my own solution to 3 out of the four key highlights :) Where have I written give me the formula? Thanks though

Comment: your current formula checks line by line regardless of the matching user id.  Is that the way you really want it? Or do you want to check dates where user id matches?

Comment: That is not the way - correct. Ideally, would want to check dates where user ID matches rather than checking each line which is resulting in blank rows & 0's

Comment: so, given the data, there are no dates for matching ids that are greater than the previous month.  So you would return a blank list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FILTER and XLOOKUP:

```
=FILTER(A2:A9,C2:C9>XLOOKUP(A2:A9,E2:E9,G2:G9,999999),"")
```

[image]